# How to fetch in Slick 3.x?

Tags: playframework, slick

I have the following code, it connects OK to the database, however I don't know how to print each row (the equivalent to `rs.next` in JDBC):

```
val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
try {
    val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]
    // fetch each user and print it
    println("user : " + ??? )

} finally db.close
```

Any help will be appreciated, apologies for the newbie question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. The important consideration is that the result set returns a "Future", meaning that the response is asynchronous (as opposed to synchronous in Java):

```
val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
try {
    val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]
    val action = users.result
    val future = db.run(action)

    future onComplete {
      case Success(u) => u.foreach { user  => println("user : " + user ) }
      case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
    }

} finally db.close
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#querying). I am also new to scala and slick. Hope this will help you.

```
val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
try {
    val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]

    // fetch each user and print it
    // You need to import database driver...
    // import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._

    val usersListQueryResult = db.run(users.result) //it returns, Future[R]

    // Now you can use blocking or non blocking call
    val userList = Await.result(usersListQueryResult, Duration("60 seconds")) //Blocking
    // OR 
    usersListQueryResult.foreach(println) //NonBlocking
} finally db.close
```

Comment: I'm trying the non blocking option and it does not return anything, could it be that I need to (somehow) wait until the result is available? thanks

Comment: Yes, somehow you have to wait. In scala you can also do future composition. Please check the  official documentation. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Answer (score 1):

You may also try the following

```
val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
try {
    val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]

    val printingAction:DBIO[Unit] =
      for{seqUsers <- users.result}  // DBIO[Seq[User]]
        for{ user <- seqUsers}       // simple executable code, :Unit 
          println("user : " + user )

    val future = db.run(printingAction)
    Await.result(future, 60.seconds) // need to wait before close db    
} finally db.close
```

(which is very similar to @Shakil's answer)

Answer (score 1):

There is another option in Slick: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/dbio.html#streaming

```
val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
try {
    val users: TableQuery[Users] = TableQuery[Users]    
    val p: DatabasePublisher[User] = db.stream(users.result)
    p.foreach { user  => println("user : " + user ) }
} finally db.close
```